# Поиск в списке из словарей

Tags: python, list, dict

У меня список из словарей:

```
my_list = [{'a':'1', 'inplay':'True', 'b':'2'},
           {'c':'3', 'd':'4'},
           {'e':'5', 'inplay':'False', 'f':'6'}]
```

Мне необходимо получить индекс элемента списка, то есть порядковый номер того словаря, в котором `inplay == 'False'`. Чтобы ответ был `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант реализации: пройтись по всем словарям --- лементам списка, для каждого проверить:

1. Если ключа нет, сразу пропускаем словарь
2. Если ключ есть, то, если значение по ключу совпадает с переданным в функцию, вернём индекс элемента и сам элемент внутри кортежа.

```py
def find_by_key(iterable, key, value):
    for index, dict_ in enumerate(iterable):
        if key in dict_ and dict_[key] == value:
            return (index, dict_)
```

```py
In [10]: my_list = [{'a':'1', 'inplay':'True', 'b':'2'},
    ...:            {'c':'3', 'd':'4'},
    ...:            {'e':'5', 'inplay':'False', 'f':'6'}]

In [11]: find_by_key(my_list, "inplay", "False")
Out[11]: (2, {'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'inplay': 'False'})
```

Если хочется найти все элементы, удовлетворяющие условию, можно
создать функцию-генератор:

```py
def find_all_by_key(iterable, key, value):
    for index, dict_ in enumerate(iterable):
        if key in dict_ and dict_[key] == value:
            yield (index, dict_)
```

```py
In [22]: my_list = [{"inplay": "False", "a": 1},
    ...:            {"inplay": "True", "a": 37},
    ...:            {"inplay": "False", "a": 153, "b": "hello"}]

In [23]: list(find_all_by_key(my_list, "inplay", "False"))
Out[23]: 
[(0, {'a': 1, 'inplay': 'False'}),
 (2, {'a': 153, 'b': 'hello', 'inplay': 'False'})]
```

Эквивалентная запись:

```py
def find_all_by_key(iterable, key, value):
    return ((index, dict_) for index, dict_ in enumerate(iterable)
            if key in dict_ and dict_[key] == value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for result, dic_ in enumerate(my_list):
    if dic_.get('inplay', '') == 'False':
        break;
else:
    result = None
```

---

*Объяснение*:

Функцией `enumerate()`, примененной к вашему списку `my_list`, получим в переменной `result` порядковое число очередного элемента, и в переменной `dic_` сам элемент — словарь.

Методом `.get('inplay', '')` примененным к словарю `dic_` мы получим `dic_['inplay']`, когда ключ `'inplay'` существует, или пустую строку в противном случае.

Командой `break` мы окончим поиск высечением из цикла, только что мы нашли желанный индекс — этот индекс тут находится в переменной `result`.

Когда команда `break` не была применена, значит, когда желанный индекс не был найден, выполнится ветвь `else` (да, цикл `for` может иметь ветвь `else`), в которой мы присвоим переменной `result` какое-то значение для индикации, что поиск не был успешным.